# How to convert TwitterResponse to something that ListView can read?

Tags: asp.net, twitterizer

I've been googling for a really long time, and there is no example of how to display TwitterResponse object to something that datagrid or listview can display ... anyone has any solution to that ?

BTW, i tried to convert TwitterResponse to JSON Object, and itz just chaos ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used it, but it's clear from the documentation for Twitterizer that you need to bind to the `ResponseObject` property of the `TwitterResponse` object. *If* that is enumerable and contains properties then you should be able to bind to it.

Comment: I used a very complicated way ... convert it to a JSONObject i found in Facebook SDK, and dictionary.Dictionary it ... but , thanks for the help !